# Safely injecting HTML into a Polymer template

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

In a custom element, I try to replace an item's body text with HTML for line breaks and links. It was working when I just handled line breaks (nl2br()), but no longer when handling links (linkify()).

```dart
  get formattedBody {
    if (item.isEmpty) return 'Loading...';
    return "${InputFormatter.nl2br(InputFormatter.linkify(item['body']))}";
  }

  itemChanged() {
    // Trick to respect line breaks.
    HtmlElement body = $['body'];
    body.innerHtml = formattedBody;
  }
```

I get a warm and safe security message e.g.:

```dart
Removing disallowed attribute <A href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/the-starting-gate/2014/09/news-.html">
```

I also tried `setInnerHtml()`, to no avail.

Ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a `<safe-html>` element working. Verified on Chrome and even post-dart2js on Safari. Vote up this answer if you'd like me to turn it into a lib available on pub.dartlang.org.

Usage:

```dart
<safe-html validator="{{nodeValidator}}">{{someHtml}}</safe-html>
```

(Passing in your own `validator` is optional. Without it, we'll use a default.)

safe_html.html:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../../../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="safe-html">
  <template>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src='safe_html.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

safe_html.dart:

```dart
library safe_html;

import 'dart:async';
import "dart:html";

import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

@CustomTag("safe-html")
class SafeHtml extends PolymerElement  {
  @published NodeValidator validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowHtml5(uriPolicy: new DefaultUriPolicy());

  SafeHtml.created() : super.created();

  addFragment() {
    DivElement container = $['container'];
    String fragment =  this.text;
    container.setInnerHtml(fragment, // Set the fragment in a safe way.
      validator: validator);
    this.text = ""; // Clear the original fragment passed to the element.
  }

  attached() {
    addFragment();
  }
}

class DefaultUriPolicy implements UriPolicy {
  DefaultUriPolicy();

  // Allow all external, absolute URLs.
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'(?:http://|https://|//)?.*');

  bool allowsUri(String uri) {
    return regex.hasMatch(uri);
  }
}
```

If you choose to pass your own `NodeValidator`, do it by specifying a getter in the parent element that uses `<safe-html>`:

```dart
NodeValidator get nodeValidator => new NodeValidatorBuilder()
..allowHtml5(uriPolicy: new ItemUrlPolicy());
```

As you can see I reference a `UriPolicy` which I keep in a separate file like uri_policy.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class ItemUrlPolicy implements UriPolicy {
  ItemUrlPolicy();

  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'(?:http://|https://|//)?.*');

  bool allowsUri(String uri) {
    return regex.hasMatch(uri);
  }
}
```

With lots of help from Günter Zöchbauer and the authors of other helpful posts on SO.

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to ensure `html` is not `null`? `if(html == null) html = ''` before `content.setInnerHtml(html,...` ?

Comment: Not quite, because `html` is not what's `null`, it's the result of `this.text = '';` or similar attempts. https://github.com/woven/dart-communities/blob/3450a02141e5c748efde178adb7b26dbdcf37573/lib/src/client/components/widgets/safe_html/safe_html.dart It's like it writes a `null` right inside `<content>` before the other stuff prints – only in Safari after pub build.

Comment: I don't have Safari to test but you assign `html` after `this.text = '';`. What is `this.text` supposed to do anyway?. Why are you using a `<content>`? `<content>` is not supposed to have content. `<content>` is just a placeholder for Polymer to know where to project the children of the polymer element.

Comment: Ok so I can simply read the innerHtml to get the literal html, then process it and set back the validated stuff, no content tag needed?

Comment: If you use the `<content>` tag you can manipulate the children/innerHtml of `<safe-html>` like you did with `this.text = '';` to get the desired effect. If you don't use a `<content>` tag you can manipulate the `shadowRoot.children` or add a placeholder tag of some kind (div, span, ...) into the shadowDOM of `<safe-html>` (like I did in the linked example) and manipulate its children/innherHtml.

Comment: Ok, I've updated w/ what's now working. Gone are the null issues post dart2js. How's it look to you? One thing that feels odd is how I can't just do `String fragment =  this.text; this.setInnerHtml(fragment, validator: validator);` and instead need the container so the fragment gets inserted into the shadowRoot.

Comment: Yes and thank you! See comments above and edited answer. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a `NodeValidator` which is configured to allow specific tags and attributes.

This question [HTML Tags Within Internationalized Strings In Polymer.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868296) contains an example of a custom element that allows to pass HTML using polymer expressions. The implementation demonstrates how to use `NodeValidator`.

Instead of `..allowTextElements()` you can allow other sets of elements/attributes or custom elements/attributes. Autocompletion should show the possible options.

See also
- [Dart, why does using innerHtml to set shadow root content work but appendHtml doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000995)
- [Dart Removing disallowed attribute after editor upgraded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867266)
- [Mustache Template usage in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767566)
- [in dart parse HTML string to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467115)

I got it working with

```dart
NodeValidator nodeValidator = new NodeValidatorBuilder()
    ..allowNavigation(new MiamiHeraldUrlPolicy());

aContainer.setInnerHtml('<a href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/the-starting-gate/2014/09/news-.html">bla</a>', 
    validator: nodeValidator);
```

```dart
class MiamiHeraldUrlPolicy implements UriPolicy {
  MiamiHeraldUrlPolicy();

  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'(?:http://|https://|//)?miamiherald.typepad.com/.*');

  bool allowsUri(String uri) {
    return regex.hasMatch(uri);
  }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? When tags/attributes are removed this is logged to the console.

Comment: Even w/ the more liberal `allowHtml5()` I get: Removing disallowed attribute <A href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/the-starting-gate/2014/09/news-.html">
+ItemActivities
Removing disallowed attribute <A href="http://miamiherald.typepad.com/the-starting-gate/2014/09/news-.html">

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/woven/dart-communities/commit/fe9fe3f6b937aad34bad9c4efade7ddfa9a73dd9 Off to bed, to return soon.

Comment: Great. Makes sense. Got it working without the safe-html element. I wonder how, given the .setInnerHtml(), to get it working w/ that element?

Comment: I'm almost there, but the issue I had is when I passed `model="{{formatText(someText)}}"` it returned and injected the actual HTML into the attribute thus breaking the whole page. So I then tried to move the format function into safe-html, like https://gist.github.com/davenotik/d3fa3b7c02333055d747, but I'm getting a hard to trace error: `Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function`.